# Should answers with higher votes have a visual hint?

Tags: discussion

The accepted question, if any, is acknowledged with a green mark and I also see that is sorted (desc) by number of votes, but I wonder if some users would find interesting to see a symbol to indicate that the answer is not marked as accepted but has a high number of votes.

Perhaps a yellow check mark or exclamation.

Comment: The number of votes displayed next to the question, and the fact that the highest-voted question appears first in the list, are very strong visual hints. What benefit is gained by adding more?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: Maybe there should be a hint on the accept mark if the accepted answer has less than half the upvotes of the highest upvoted answer? Maybe make the mark dotted or some such? That's only relevant for quite long accepted answers though...

Comment: if there is not a marked as accepted answer, it highlights the fact that it has high "acceptance". On the other hand, I've seen answers where the users only pay attention to the marked as accepted even if there is one with higher votes. Human nature? Laziness? not sure but visual cues help a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad suggestion at all. Sure regular users know (or not, based on the number of meta questions about it) that the checkmark only means it is the answer the asker found most useful. But to passers-by it could certainly be mistaken for a mark of "deemed the best answer by the community".

Comment: I've seen so many times scenarios like [Properties vs Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) where a developer in my team didn't even pay attention to the one with higher votes, which in in IMHO rendered a better explanation.
Again, we are developers but at the end we are also humans.

Comment: Posted my comment as a feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho, things are clear enough: the green mark means the answer is accepted, and then answers are sorted from highest to lowest voted by default.

The only visual cue that might be missing is one suggested in this question's comments: to make the mark e.g. red or orange when an answer is voted higher than the accepted one.

Comment: The trouble with that suggestion is it is only helpful to regular users of the site. Someone coming from google isn't going to know that red or orange means they need to look at the answer below it.

Comment: @OGHaza: … which is no big deal when you think about it: they probably wouldn't know that one can accept an answer either.

Comment: @OGHaza: Leaving aside my suspicion that this isn't the case because western != universal, your underlying assumption is that most random visitors actually browse past the first answer and notice the checkmark. I very sincerely doubt that this is the case.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying. I was actually thinking that your solution didn't address the problem of them not scrolling past, but then nor does highlighting the next one anyway! I suppose I'm all for the top voted answer always appearing top, but here is not the place for that discussion.

Comment: I really like your suggestion but I believe we should have both a different color for a lower accepted answer and some color for the higher vote. Sounds cliche but "A picture is worth a thousand words"