# Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Any accepted answer currently get a bright, big green accept mark.

While everyone on SO a bit longer should know this only indicates the OPs acceptance and *not* the community's judgement, it is quite eye-catching and also anchors the answer to the top.

My feature-request is to obviously deemphasise this mark, by making it e.g. stroked, if the community overwhelmingly prefers a different answer, like 2*score_accepted+3.

This makes it obvious even if the accepted answer is quite long that there is a probably better answer following, even at a glance.

Comment: 2x+3 seems a bit too much. 1.5x is reasonable enough IMO, maybe 1.5x+2 to account for low score answers.

Comment: I would be thinking more like 1.5 + 10 - an 5-voted answer shouldn't necessarily overrule a 2 voted answer - there could easily be frivolous voting at that level. This question is really more relevant to long-standing questions with highish votes (20+ at least), where the accepted answer is problematic. Early on, it's not so bad, as few people are going to be misled. Also, as per my comment on [La-comadreja's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253763/210945), OP's opinion is far more relevant early on - there might even be a case for only applying this weighting after a couple of weeks.

Comment: One additional reason why I started a discussion on [Should answers with higher votes have a visual hint?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253748/should-answers-with-higher-votes-have-a-visual-hint) was because I've seen some many accepted answers that looked more like "abandoned" ones: The person who asked the question never reviewed the answer again, and in several instances it was the wrong or partial answer. Either the color is lighted or just the weight takes it to the proper position.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I haven't accepted anything because nothing was done. Accepting provides a bit of closure...

Comment: Referenced in meta post *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302)* (2021-02-18).

Answer (score 113):

You know what I'm beginning to think we should do? Not pin the accepted answer to the top at all.

By default, we should sort accepted answers by votes alone. We can make the accept vote be treated as an additional vote as a tiebreaker, but I don't think that the person asking the question should have a super vote that outweighs the rest of the community.

The accepted answer will still have a big green checkmark next to it, so that visitors can see which answer worked best for the asker, but I don't think their vote should override the community. I'm getting tired of handling flags asking for outright wrong or worse answers to be unaccepted so they can be sorted below better ones, and this really does look odd to outside visitors who just want to find the best solution to the question asked.

Comment: `I'm getting tired of handling flags asking....` **THIS**

Comment: If you want to do that, how about an anchor link at the bottom of the question: "Jump to the accepted solution" ?

Comment: Better yet, abolish the concept of an accepted answer altogether. Even if we stop pinning the accepted answer to the top, that's not going to stop people from commenting "This should be the accepted answer." on the highest-voted answer. Let the OP comment "this worked for me" if they want, we'll just delete the comment after the fact. Sound fair? Let's be honest, nobody *really* gives a crap what worked for the OP, especially if it isn't the best solution. Not to mention not every OP understands the very concept either.

Comment: @BoltClock: That's a lot of hate for something that's been here since the beginning of Stack Overflow.  We might dislike the flags, but people are going to do what they're going to do anyway.

Comment: So what's the point of any of the suggestions here then? I should have just shut up.

Comment: @BoltClock - You weren't the only one to think this, which is why I asked this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose . The answers there made a strong argument for keeping accepted answers, but I'm thinking it's sort order that's the larger issue here.

Comment: Well I wouldn't be against relegating the purpose of answer acceptance to one of being an asker-upvote since askers can't otherwise vote on answers to their own questions anyway. We all have to make compromises. Let's get on with the day.

Comment: This is something I would have liked to change for a pretty long time now, but the last time it came up it was met with very heavy resistance from SE. So I'm rather skeptical that it will be different this time.

Comment: @BoltClock: "askers can't otherwise vote on answers to their own questions anyway." Wha? Sure you can vote on answers to your question. Are you thinking of the fact that, unlike comments, you can't vote under your own question unless you have the voting privilege already?

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Yes, I meant to say askers without the privilege.

Comment: @BoltClock:  "This should be the accepted answer" comments would be *a lot* less frequent, if the better answers could float above the accepted answers.

Comment: Agreed. I want to keep the checkmark, but automatically placing that answer first doesn't make sense to me because sometimes the best answer can change over time.  See this question, where an answer 7 months after the original question was posted has over 7x the votes of the accepted answer, yet appears below the fold on my laptop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565471/how-can-i-exclude-directories-from-grep-r Perhaps only showing the accepted answer first for a period of time (3-6 months?) and sorting by votes when that time expires would work.

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4697570/revisions which only got "fixed" recently (the fixed answer is still crap imho), and was 100% wrong for 3+ years. The correct answer has over 4 times the votes of the accepted answer. Is this going to happen, or is it off the table?

Comment: IMO the Marked as answer is useful pinned to the top. and 80% of the time will probably be the best answer. I think that highest rated should only overtake the best answer if it has at least x number more up votes. i.e. 2x the up votes as marked answer. Just my opinion though

Comment: @BoltClock I disagree completely with 'Let's be honest, nobody really gives a crap what worked for the OP'. At least, not with the current stance of "we don't delete incorrect answers if it's an *attempted* answer". There are plenty of unique problems with upvoted answers *that don't work* because no one could be bothered to reproduce the error, and the answer 'looks nicer' than the *actual* solution. "Accepted" answers essentially say "Yes, this *definitely* worked" to filter out answers that were "an attempt to answer but may or may not even compile or answer the question".

Comment: That being said, I do think there should be a way to have others change the accepted answer. Perhaps a user with `x` amount of reputation in the tag can update the accepted answer (maybe only if the answers have remained unchanged for some time), providing they've gone and *objectively* proved the current answer is wrong?

Comment: THIS.  This should be the way it works.  though perhaps a combination with the OP's suggestion about weighting.  perhaps the accepted answer stays at the top if it has 1/2 as many votes as the most-upvoted answer, or 1/3 or 90% or something.  but there are far too many answers that were accepted before a _better_ answer was provided, or now the advice is 5 years out of date and a different (move current) answer is 100-times better.

Answer (score 11):

The checkmark belongs to the OP.  It's not "Oh, it belongs to the OP, unless we happen to disagree."  It belongs to the OP, period.

The purpose of the checkmark is to show the intent of the OP, not the intent of the community.  The intent of the community is demonstrated by the use of upvotes and downvotes, not the color of the checkmark, or anything else.

I realize that this [sticks in the craw of people sometimes](http://xkcd.com/386/), but there it is.

Comment: OP is not asking to remove the checkmark, just to display it slightly differently depending on the case.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: I certainly concurr that the checkmark belongs to the OP. I just suggested deemphasising it when the community really strongly disagrees, so users not quite so conversant with our conventions get a good hint. (Might be useful for regulars on quick-scanning too)

Comment: That's what votes are for.  You should use them.

Comment: I agree that checkmark belongs to OP, but the point is - the accepted answer (provided it wasn't posted by the OP) is placed above all other answers independent of the score. This is bad UX in the case OP described.

Comment: Nice XKCD reference, I like it. Still, while I'm not convinced you have a good answer yet, it certainly won't break my heart if it stays just like it is.

Comment: There's nothing else to say.  You assume that nobody is going to notice that the answer right below the checkmark has twice as many upvotes as the checked one.

Comment: Of course the system works, but that doesn't mean that improvements couldn't be made.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Many people *don't* look past the first answer when they come to read a question.  They often won't even know that there *is* a second answer, unless the first answer is obviously wrong to them, at which point they continue searching for more information.  When answers are wrong in subtle ways that aren't apparent at first glance to uninformed readers, that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Servy: Have you been in the PHP tag lately?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I'm not a PHP dev, but from its reputation I would expect its regulars to support my point of view.  Unless you're considering that some people would *want* such uninformed readers to be bitten for not reading past the first answer.

Answer (score 7):

The community is not always the best judge of which answer to the original post was best.  Allowing the OP the authority in question emphasizes this.

The accepted answer is usually the one that most specifically answers the question.  Other answers might be very lovely and even outscore it, but address something slightly different.

For a couple examples of such situations in Stack Exchange, see:
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19975/is-it-a-good-idea-to-ask-a-future-employer-whether-or-not-i-might-be-allowed-to/
(Some posts for Users more fanatical about Open Source development than the OP obviously was outscored the accepted answer)

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53795/how-does-an-orc-perceive-a-hobbit/
(A post with an image outscored the accepted answer even though it was less pinpointed toward the question)

Comment: +1 for searching examples of accepted answers better suited but less loved than others. -1 for the first example being a bad one: Both answers (accepted and popular) answer the question well imho, even if they emphasise different parts of the implications of going those ways. They would both gain by added breadth, including the other answers main points. As an aside, those are not on SO but elsewhere on the SE network: You might want to go for SO examples for more weight. In the end: Thank you for a good reply.

Comment: @Deduplicator That can happen on any of the SE sites, SO isn't immune from people voting up answers for silly reasons such as a picture or meme that was included in the answer.

Comment: The accepted answer usually best answers *the OP's interpretation* of the question. Of course initially that is paramount, but once the OP is satisfied, *all* of the answers more or less useless to them (as it's now information they know). Later, thousands of other users come to find an answer to their own interpretation of the question, via search engines, etc. Answers are then far more relevant *to them* than to the OP. Up votes are a good indication of the *most likely interpretation of the question*, with OP's subjectivity removed. At that point, the community *is* the best judge.

Comment: Yes, quite often the higher voted answer will be a "rethink your approach" answer, whereas the accepted answer will be a "even though what you're doing is crazy, this is how to do what you asked" answer. The latter makes more sense to me, although a combination of the two is good also.