# Accepted Answer Vs Voted Answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

I've been in this situation many times now - where another user whose answer having more up votes than mine (or any  other user) commenting below my accepted answer to the OP why he didn't accept his answer, will you consider accepting mine etc. *(probably after spending hours to and coming up with a may or may not be improved answer build up based own other answers or not. )*

Sometimes the OP actually switches the **accepted answer - The answer that helped him and solved his problem when he needed it.**

[This Q made me post this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631822/line-below-link-on-hover/23632065#23632065) (Not exactly the thing i'm discussing here, but i had to waste my time another morning explaining and updating - and the OP might switch the accepted answer now..? :s)

Here is what i think -

One can build upon the existing answers  (Improve them, combine them.. whatever...) and come up with a better approach -  after hours, days, weeks, months or years.

Technology evolves: There might be easiest ways to do the same thing in future.

One usually seeks the help from community when he's stuck with a problem that needs to be solved. When it's solved he accepts the answer that helped him solve it. He moves on with his rest of the stuff - **End of Story.**

If one provide a better approach or better solution weeks or months after the question was asked and solved it might not help the OP : But it helps the community who refers to the question in future.
 (*Consider my case: i do projects for clients, any better solution that comes after a project is successfully delivered to clients is useless for me*).

This is where the **Upvotes** come in. If one's answer is better & helpful, the community will reward him with upvotes, which showers much more rep and future readers with commonsence can easily figure out which is the better answer by looking at the upvotes.

IMHO, An accepted answer doesn't always mean it's the best possible solution **forever** , it's a special privilege given to OP for marking the answer that helped him out **in time**.

So it'd be nice if the community stops asking OP to switch the answer pointing to others answers, instead we can always up vote the better answer…

Thoughts?

(Ok, not sure whether this is already discussed before, This is seems common nowadays. i'm not a regular meta user. Even I'm not quite sure whether i've done this before or not. i'd feel dumb if i've ever done this 0__0)

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: It's open for discussion.. if you want a question out of that - Whether the OP has to change the accepted answer since another answer has more up votes..?

Comment: @TJ My opinion on the matter of *Whether the OP has to change the accepted answer since another answer has more up votes..?*....  **No** the OP should accept whatever answer they found more useful to there question. They shouldn't be forced to change it at all. At the end of the day its there question, they get to pick what helped them most. It don't matter if a question has 2000 words that explains every little bit and the OP accepts an answer with 3 lines in it. And the end of the day its what helped them. Other users will upvote and give a reward for the answers they think are best.

Comment: @Ruddy the comment should be an answer i guess...

Comment: @TJ Its half an answer, so I didn't feel its worthy to be put as an answer. I may write an answer up a bit later with more information.

Comment: Forcing the user to change their accepted answer probably isn't the right way to approach this, but I'm really warming to altering the way we present these: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253754/19679

Answer (score 11):

Rather than changing policies, why not just visually highlight an accepted answer if there is an answer below it with more upvotes? That way people know to scroll down and check the other answers.

Comment: I was just about to post this as a solution! I think it would be great to have a visual warning if the accepted (and there fore top most) answer is not the highest rated one. Can we contact the stack overflow (or even stack exchange??) system admins, or can we just hope that they read this?

Comment: I would love to see this posed as a feature request if it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score -2):

There is a bit of confusion or misinterpretation by some users about the meaning of accepted answer hinting that it could be clarified more. The accepted answer is in practice simply the first answer that helped the questioner solve the problem partly or in whole. Independent from this there is the answer that the community regards as most helpful, indicated by highest votes. It's really two different things although often they are the same, but not always. Yesterday I saw a question with 11 votes for the accepted answer and 79 for the highest voted. It happens.

So the description "accepted answer" is partly misleading and suggest this is the right one for everybody which it isn't. in practice it's just the first one that was sufficiently good. Very often for simple problems with several identical answers it's even a randomly chosen of several equally good answers. And questioners are not required to change their vote later or consider newer answers, are they?

Finding a better description ("first working solution", "preferred by questioner", ... maybe) or displaying the acceptance mark a bit smaller or changing the default sorting order to go more for votes - all these are possible features which also could be helpful. These are all proposed somewhere but as far as I know without realization so far.

Answer (score -5):

Based on the semantics of accepted and upvoted answers, I would suggest a small change of policy:

- you should not be able to change the accepted answer after some short time (e.g. 48 hours), as an accepted answer is indeed meant to point to the answer that **originally helped the OP**;
- the accepted answer should not be on top of other answers that have more up votes, as the ranking is there to **help other users, not the OP**. Answers should be ranked by popularity without consideration for an answer being the accepted answer (except maybe in case of a tie).

Comment: What if I try to run with one answer, but I only later find out it is subtly flawed, maybe after someone else gave a superb answer avoiding those pitfalls? The newer answer *is*  the one that helped me most, even though the other one seemed to solve my problem by sending me on a wild-geese search. Even if it's not such a blatant case, who says the OP does not reread everything when he gets a new answer, might learn a lot, and so in balance the new answer helped him more?

Comment: But that's not the semantics of an accepted answer, which is the first answer that helped you. After that, the OP should not have any more privilege than any other SO user. He may still use his votes, like anybody else. And if another answer is of better quality it should rise on top if the accepted answer.

Comment: If the accepted answer was locked so that the OP could not remove the accepted tick, then the answer would also have to be locked to edits to prevent the tick being on an answer changed beyond recognition. I'm against both. This site is collaborative and ongoing.