# Subpar accepted answer, OP no longer around to unaccept

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

**Scenario:** A question is asked where various different solutions could be classed as correct, and the OP accepts the one that they found useful at the time.

Months later, a different solution is posted (one which ends up vastly outscoring the accepted answer).

As the OP doesn't seem to use StackOverflow anymore, there is no way to ask them to unaccept the currently accepted answer and tick the superior one (note that the accepted answer isn't wrong per se, it just isn't as good/useful in comparison).

What is the standard procedure here?

Unsure whether to:

- flag a mod to remove the answer as accepted/delete it if necessary
- edit it to include a link reference to the superior answer
- community wiki edit it to include a reference to all the different possible solutions
- or just leave it.

---

**Edit:** Apologies, I am asking it from the perspective of when the accepted answer is your own.

Comment: Leave it. Accepts are used to indicate what worked for the OP, upvotes are used to indicate what worked for the community in general.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255706/why-are-negative-score-accepted-answers-still-at-the-top

Comment: since you're the answerer, edit it to include a link reference (preferably along with a brief explanation) to the superior answer. That way, you'll turn weakness into power: site visitors seeing your answer on top, will be immediately and authoritatively redirected to "the right way"

Answer (score 9):

If you feel that an answer is not helpful you can downvote it.  You can also comment on the answer explaining why you think it's not helpful.

Those are the *only* acceptable actions for an answer you think is not helpful due to its technical content.

If you flag it the mod will just decline your flag and be annoyed that you wasted their time.   It's not their job to judge the technical accuracy of posts.

It is absolutely not your place to edit another person's answer to link to an answer that you think is better.  It's their answer, they can answer the question however they want to.  If you don't like it you can express that through voting, not editing.

Taking someone else's answer and turning it into a community wiki so that you can then put in a bunch of other content that is not theirs is no better.  Again, it's their answer, they can answer the question however they want to.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to write this question in a neutral way - the answer is mine, not written by someone else.

Comment: @dsg If it's your post you can of course edit it to say whatever you want it to say, or just delete it if you think it's not helpful.

Comment: @Servy Can you delete an accepted answer?

Comment: @Louis [no](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272849/839601)

Comment: @Louis You can ask a mod to delete it.  It would be the one case where a flag would be appropriate.

Comment: @Servy In a case like this, I'd expect the delete request to turn into a dissociation.

Comment: @Louis Why?  I see no good reason to disassociate here, and every reason to delete.  The only reason to disaccociate would be if someone wanted to delete the post out of spite, because they were ragequitting.  If it's honestly clear that it's not a good post and that there is a better solution, the correct action is most certainly to delete the post.  Dissociation also in no way deals with the fact that the post is accepted.

Comment: @Servy Well, wouldn't deletion mean the OP would lose the +2 rep from accepting? Does not seem right to me. There's also a general bias against just deleting answers that are merely not great. Then again I'm not a mod here or anywhere else on the SE network so...

Comment: @Louis If they're not active anymore then why would they care about losing 2 rep?  If they're not, the can accept the better answer.  That 2 rep is going to have a miniscule impact, but having a bad answer to a question around, and worse as the accepted answer, is a *much* bigger problem.  Deleting *someone else's answer* because it has technical problems is not acceptable, deleting *your own* answer because you feel it has technical problems is entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Why should the OP "unaccept" the answer they've accepted if something better comes along? It seems to me the desire that the OP unaccept can only come from a misunderstanding of what acceptance means. **The acceptance mark means that at some point the OP found the answer helpful. It does not mean "this is the best answer of the lot."**

Maybe some time later a better answer came along but **this does not change the fact that the OP found the accepted answer helpful**. Note that I'm not saying that the OP cannot change their mind. I'm saying that new answers do not change the past, nor do they create an obligation on the part of the OP to change their earlier decision.

What you *can* do if you find an accepted answer is faulty is downvote it and comment. The edits you are suggesting are likely to be found illegitimate because they change the substance of the answer. A flag won't do anything since a deficient answer is still an answer.

If the problematic answer is your own, I guess you could perform the edits you suggested. I would not lose sleep over it though. In a case where the answer you posted is embarrassing, you could ask for dissociation.

Comment: "Why should the OP "unaccept" the answer they've accepted if something better comes along?". Because currently a side effect of acceptance is that it pins the answer to the top in prime position. So currently the only way of correcting this and putting the best answer first would be for the OP  to change their accept.

Comment: @MartinSmith The fix for that would be to remove the rule about pinning the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree but this has been requested many times and not implemented.

Comment: The idea of the accepted answer appearing at the top is *that the OP found it the most helpful*. It can be a link only, it can be a one-liner (or, in the case of a yes/no question, one single word), or it can be faulty, buggy, and ugly code. But it *did* help the OP enough, at the time of accepting. Downvote if it's so bad it's not a good answer, upvote those which are better.

Answer (score -3):

There are basic problems with the current concept of "accepted answer":

First. Most problems are not "sticked" to one person, especially not the lucky one who asked it first. Choosing a good answer is a skill, and it can generate a huge influence (google etc.) for years.

Second. Often, users accept a relatively passable answer suddenly - than disappear. They do not deal with the fact that they can get a response that is better, even for them. Even if they are notified.

Third. Actually, who cares that a solution was (probably) proven for the random lucky-one first asker?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top