# Should a user be informed when the answer they accepted has its up votes overtaken?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I have a couple of questions where I gave an answer considerably after the question was originally asked, and they have since been up voted by far more than the accepted answer: [When drawing an arc using CGContextAddArcToPoint(), what does (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709794/when-drawing-an-arc-using-cgcontextaddarctopoint-what-does-x1-y1-and-x2-y2/18992153#18992153) and [CGPathAddArc vs CGPathAddArcToPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127/cgpathaddarc-vs-cgpathaddarctopoint/19065433#19065433) Would it be a good idea to inform the question asker when the accepted answer's up votes are overtaken by another answer, particularly if the answer is quite late?

Comment: For positively scored accepted answers, this would be too noisy. However, if the accepted answer is heavily downvoted (-5, for example), perhaps a notification would make sense.

Comment: At what point @Yannis? Any new answer would outscore the heavily downvoted one right from the start.

Comment: @Bart I don't think there's a reason to compare with other answers if the accepted one reaches a -5 net score. Even if there isn't any other answer, I think there's some value in educating newer users that a -5 answer probably isn't the answer they are looking for.

Comment: Ah @Yannis, I misunderstood. Ah "hey, what you've selected seems to be dropping score fast" might be an idea. Then again, how likely is it to cause a true re-evaluation ...

Comment: Do you want to deprive folks of all those Populist badges? ;)

Comment: I think the real issue is [Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253752/1287812)

Answer (score 7):

A question has two audiences: the original person asking the question, and everyone with the same or similar problem visiting later, sometimes *much* later. Those two audiences each have their own opinion about what answers are helpful, and differences in those opinions **are fine**.

The person asking the question was notified when the new answer came in, and for reasons unknown ignored it or it didn't change their mind. Notifying them of the fact that the other audience disagreed with what answer was the most helpful is not going to make a difference, nor should it.

Comment: I'd have thought that for a question with a well up voted answer, a better time to review the answer would be when a new answer is doing well rather than as soon as a new answer appeared.

Comment: @JamesSnook: Why? That answer hasn't changed from when it was posted. The OP is entitled to their own opinion, they get to mark something as most helpful *to them*. Why does the OP have to change their mind when the community disagrees?

Comment: They don't have to change their mind. There is more incentive for them to actually review the answer as there is already evidence that it may be useful to them.

Comment: Again, that call would already have been made when it was posted. And take into account that the OP has already moved on, they already solved their problem. They probably *don't care anymore*, not when the new answer was posted, and not when it was upvoted past the previously accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah because people when they've already fixed their code thoroughly look through every new answer. I feel there're more likely to be interested in looking through a new answer properly at the point that it's shown to be a good answer.

Comment: Besides, it is already established that the accepted answer is their choice, their prerogative. Why is it such a problem that you feel the OP should be poked more to change their mind?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is necessary. User are already notified when the new answer is posted. If they didn't evaluate it to be better or more worthy of acceptance at that point, I don't see why we should poke them again later on.

Acceptance of an answer doesn't mean the answer was the most correct or the best liked by the community. It merely means it's the answer that they appreciated most. Nothing more than that.

Comment: *shakes fist* @InfiniteRecursion