# The best answers are voted up and rise to the top

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I made an answer that was accepted and had 1 upvote. Another answer had 2 upvotes. That's okay, there are really close and in terms of score the top answer is better (1*10 + 15) > (2*20).

This reminded me of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716300/2411320) of mine with 141 votes, while the top (and accepted) answer has 68. However:

[image]

which is nice. So the sorting goes by score, but the accepted answer does get on top regardless of the score difference, giving the power to the single user to decide, instead of the community? I mean 141 towards 68 is a big difference. Or is there some threshold value? For example 200 votes towards 50 votes, then the 200 votes answer goes on top regardless which one the user accepts?

On the other hand I thought that this was okay, since I expect the users to check at least the second answer too. But, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614396/what-does-i-i-i-1-1-do) of mine made me think twice and make this post! I got some good answers and it was hard for me deciding which one to choose. Before that, the two top answers by [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks) and [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) were side by side, but after I accepted one (but I was not really sure which one to accept, both were fine! I mean I might decided wrong), it's score was incremented much more than the other, which indicates that most users didn't bother to read the 2nd answer, or where already fed by the 1st one.

---

***Long story short***:

How to decide which answer is better? By listening to majority of votes or by listening to the user? Or both?

**Super** relevant [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253754/2411320) that pretty muchs seems it up. (thanks to Deduplicator)!

Comment: What do you mean by *"better"*? The accepted answer is the one that **the asker found most useful**, but it may not fit your use case. *"How to decide which answer is better?"* - read them all and see how they apply to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: If that were an answer here, I'd upvote it.

Comment: That's what I am saying @jonrsharpe. People tend to check only the top answer. By allowing the user to decide which is the top answer, SO allows the user to make a possible mistake (like I *may* have done), despite the voice of the people.

Comment: @Cerbrus has a point. That would answer my question, since the key for sorting seems to be the accepted answer, despite the number of votes every answer has.

Comment: If people only check the top answer, then frankly, that's their own problem. If someone took the effort to look on SO for the solution to a problem, he shouldn't stop at the first result he gets.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253754

Comment: I agree, but I am fairly sre @Cerbrus that if I had accepted Sourav's answer, then this one would have a 200 score.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes yes yes yes yes yes. That's what I had in mind! I will edit.

Comment: @gsamaras: people _shouldn't_ vote for an answer based on wether or not it's accepted... (key word: _"shouldn't"_)

Comment: @Cerbrus I do not think they do it because of this. They do it because it's on top!

Comment: We sort of assume that you're not a moron, and can therefore read a few answers and evaluate their relevance to your own scenario! *"People tend to check only the top answer."* - that is a bad move on their part...

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe I agree and I would like them not to do so. However, as I stated this seems to not be the case and it would be nice that SO would be aware of it. so that it can ***protect*** itself!

Comment: *"protect itself"* from what, exactly?

Comment: You can't blame people for checking only the top answer when answers are sorted top-down by score in the first place. That's the whole **point** of sorting answers by score. The best information (decided by vote) goes up top. Not everyone has the attention span or the time to read through every answer to a question.

Comment: In the same vein, regardless of whether people should or shouldn't vote on an answer based on its position or based on its overall score or whatever, the reality is that **it happens** and you can't stop them from voting however they like or however they *will* vote instinctively. I'd like to see someone explain why the branch prediction question has an excess of 10k votes, and the answer an excess of 15k votes, when there are *hundreds* of other Q&As that are twice as popular but with only a fraction of the votes.

Comment: jonrsharpe from not having the best answer at top. BoltClock, the accepted answer goes on top, as it seems. But the duplicate gave me the answer already. @Deduplicator why you didn't accept the answer?