# Does the utility of selecting an answer outweigh an vote-only system?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

The paradigm of Stack Exchange is that the person asking a question selects the accepted answer. Does the act of selecting an answer positively affect the quality of the information presented on the page? Would Stack Exchange be better with an vote-only paradigm?

Some things to consider:

1. The OP may not be the most qualified person to select an answer. Although they asked the question, and know the specifics of their situation, their question may be equally applicable to hundreds of other people who have a better grasp of the the problem. An OP may hastily accept an answer that is far from ideal.
2. Selected answers can appear before more upvoted answers which increases the chances that a visitor to the post will miss the more valuable answer due to not scrolling enough. In a hypothetical situation where the accepted answer has 10 upvotes, but another answer has 100, which answer do Stack Exchange users typically spend more time considering? Should the most universally valuable answer not be presented first?
3. Often an OP will ask a question whose answer has applications beyond the OP's specific needs. The OP is selecting the answer that is best for them, but not necessarily the best answer for the general question that has been presented.

Is there some greater utility to accepting answers that outweighs these drawbacks?

**EDIT:** this previously said "upvote-only", but I did not mean to imply get rid of down-votes.  This question is more about the appropriateness/usefulness of presenting selected answers first on the page a question which is also asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers).

Comment: There are many posts containing an accepted answer, where other answers there have a lot more upvotes. The votes are very probably the better quality indicator.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't think he is suggestion getting rid of downvotes, just acceptance

Comment: Per the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (emphasis mine: *"Accepting an answer is **not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly**. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later."*

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not suggesting editing, just interpreting :)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Makes sense. Hopefully the OP will chime in.

Comment: `the person answering a question selects the accepted answer.` No.  The person who ask the question and only that person gets to accept an answer if they want to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you could make the argument though that the millions of people viewing a question don't read the help page. The visual emphasis, to the untrained eye, really *is* that a question has been definitively answered, and that input is no longer required.

Comment: I don't see actual concrete problems from having an additional checkmark showing what worked for the author. The only debatable downside is that the most upvoted answer might not appear on 1st but 2nd place. However *noone* will stop reading after an accepted answer if it didn't satisfy *them*. And if it did - mission accomplished. Your 3 points are only an issue if people would think that an accepted answer is *the absolute truth* or best possible answer ever. Noone thinks that.

Comment: I don't see #3 as a drawback. It sounds more like an argument for giving the Asker the option to accept an answer than against it.

Comment: And as for #2, SE has considered this and even included the [Populist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist) badge.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for catching that typo!

Comment: @ryanyuyu, sorry for the confusion.  My bad on using the wrong terminology.  I meant simply "vote"; I think down-votes are valuable.  E.g. I love how many downvotes my question is getting!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you correctly intuited my intent.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BrianRisk thanks for editing.  I'm going to cleanup my now obsolete comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some greater utility to accepting answers that outweighs
>   these drawbacks?

It encourages people to answer the actual question being asked and not just the general case, which in turn encourages people to ask questions. How many people would post questions if they never got a solution to their problem? How often would people try to solve for the specific case if they're less likely to get rep for doing so?

As I said in the comments, the OP having the ability to mark which answer worked in their specific case is a good thing, not a drawback. Sometimes you actually do have the exact problem the OP is having and being able to see which one works for that problem is useful.

Answer (score 5):

I like the feature request to have the [highest voted question on top even if there is an accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers).  With that said even before I started contributing on SO and was merely directed to it by google when looking for an answer I didn't just stop at the ✓ answer.  I would read most if not all of the answer see different/alternate approaches and I would decide myself what you use/try.  Anyone that just blindly copies code from some webpage and uses it is asking for trouble:

[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png]

<sub>source: https://xkcd.com/327/</sub>

I don't think we should get rid of the ✓ as it demonstrates that the OP was able to solve their problem with that answer and it rewards the answerer for donating their time to help others.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "Deemphasise the accept mark...." post.  The top up-voted response pretty much nails it.

Comment: While yes, people should read other answers than just the top-sorted one, the whole reason for the design of this site is to present the most relevant information quickly. That's why I'm strongly in favor of changing the sort order to always present the highest-voted answer first, with the accept vote merely acting as a tiebreaker and visual signal. So many people are confused as to why this site sorts lower or even negatively voted answers ahead of higher voted ones simply because of one person's decision.