# Should there be a circumstance where the highest-rated answer comes before the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

Today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c), looked at the top answer in the list and assumed that was the best solution as it had 94 up votes. I then came back and saw a far better solution below it that had 424 up votes.

The answer with 94 up votes was the first in the list because it was the answer that the OP accepted. Should there be a circumstance where the number of up votes moves the answer to the top? In this case the second answer in the list has 300% more up votes than the top answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253754/922184

Comment: That answered my question. Thanks. As an aside I would say that by default marked answers should be pinned unless the vote is significantly higher. i.e double that of the marked answer. Just my opinion though

Comment: @user1 You should probably add that comment to the dupe target as it gets more traffic.

Comment: @NathanOliver good point. Have added my 2 cents