# Improve UX by adding alert another answer may be more useful

Tags: feature-request, answers

If there is clearly another answer that is better (more up votes by X%) than the accepted answer, then an alert should be displayed linking the user to the answer with said up votes.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers