# Is the concept of "accepted answer" no longer needed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Why do we do this?

We are a community site.  There are lots of answers and they get voted by the community as to what is better or not in response to the question.

But we give special credence to the OP selecting the "best" answer for them, like some technical Cards Against Humanity, though there are a lot of issues with accepted answers (looking through Meta for issues with users not accepting answers, or users accepting answers too quickly, or the accepted answer being wrong, or the accepted answer being wrong over time as the technology changes.)

So why do we still do it?

I think we should punt the whole idea.  The best answer is the answer the community declares is the best answer.  We allow the community to make changes to almost everything else - we can edit questions and answers, we can delete questions (and reopen them).  If we can't influence the "right" answer (we can't change the "accepted" answer), let's get rid of the whole thing.

Comment: Questioning if site features are still relevant is a good thing, but accepted does not imply the best answer, with or without quotes. It even does not necessarily represent a correct answer. Sure, people may assume it to be so when they see a green checkmark next to an answer... the way this feature is presented is something I do find problematic, but that has been discussed at length already.

Comment: @Gimby If all the site did was put a green checkmark next to it then that sentiment would have merit, but given that the site always puts it above every other answer, and always considers such answers "good" answers for the purpose of all heuristics and automated processes, even when it's demonstrated that it's not the case, the site is very loudly telling all readers that the accepted answer *is* the best answer. A few people on meta saying otherwise can't really compete with that.

Comment: @Servy agreed, those are some easy examples of why the presentation is really badly implemented. I do remember a feature request that changed the look of the checkmark to something else that was a lot more fitting, can't find it yet though...

Comment: @gnat this is really broader than that: are "accepted answers" useful in what is meant to be a community-managed Q&A site?  Just because we answer the question for someone (at a specific point in time) should we give the OP any say in that it's answered?

Comment: per my reading [this answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253763/839601) covers this fairly well (ironically it is also least voted at the moment)

Comment: For me, when I go looking for questions to answer, I tend to skip over any questions that have a green mark already as I can consider that resolved.  It helps target questions that still need help answering instead of going through each one.  I think it would slow the process down too much without it.  Only so much time in the day! :)

Answer (score 15):

It signals that there's an answer that worked for the user that asked the question. In other words, it "closes" the "issue".

Such a mark *is* helpful.
Sure, it may not always be the *best* option that's selected, but more often than not, it is.

Don't look at that green icon as a indicator for the "best" answer. Votes are often more accurate to determine answer quality.

Comment: Is this the place where we start [that talk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/1233251) again? :x

Comment: "In other words, it 'closes' the 'issue'."  But it doesn't, *and we don't want it to*.  We want people to keep posting answers if they have a better one.  We want people to keep improving the question, and existing answers.  Nothing about the acceptance ought to close the issue in any way.

Comment: @Servy: Hence the "air quotes". It solves the problem for the OP. It's sort-of a "soft close".

Comment: @E_net4: No, that question is the place for that talk.

Comment: "Sure, it may not always be the best option that's selected, but more often than not, it is." And yet the site *treats* it as if it's *always* the best option, by keeping it always at the top of the list, even when it's not the best solution.  "Don't look at that green icon as a indicator for the 'best' answer. Votes are often more accurate to determine answer quality." We keep telling this to people, and yet *the site* does the opposite.  The site treats the accepted answer as the best answer, and considers it more than it considers votes.  The features on the site should reflect that quote.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not saying it *doesn't* do that, I'm saying it *shouldn't*.  We don't *want* people to consider the issue "closed", because the whole point of the site is that we're not just here to help the OP, we're here to create a useful repository for all programmers.  Treating questions as closed just because the OP was helped goes against that goal.

Comment: @Servy: I agree that the green check is over-valued, but that's a different FR. This question is asking to remove the mark completely. That, I don't agree with.

Comment: @Cerbrus Removing a bad feature would be better than leaving it.  Fixing it so that it worked properly would of course be better.

Comment: Soft-closed. Not the same as closed. I mean that you can't expect the OP to respond if you post an answer (long) after the OP accepted one. That's what I mean with "soft-closed". Like "Resolved", or "No longer looking for answers".

Comment: I disagree with the _"Removal in favor of keeping it"_ sentiment, @Servy. Especially on a core feature that's been part of the site as long as that. Sure, for something new that doesn't work (documentation), toss it, but you can't just remove accepting answers. Not to mention that fixing it would be trivial: remove the sorting priority.

Comment: @Cerbrus Once again, I'm not saying that accepting an answer *doesn't* "soft close" a question, I'm saying that *it shouldn't*.  We don't want* people to treat such questions as "no longer looking for answers", and we don't want to treat it any more or less resolved than any other question with a high quality answer (for the purposes of someone searching for a solution to that problem).  That the OP is no longer searching for an answer is simply irrelevant; we're not here just to answer the OP.  The fact that accepting an answer does "soft close" a question *is a problem*.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure, I'd far rather it be fixed, especially given how easy so many of the fixes would be, and I'm well aware that SO *won't* actually change it in any way (whether removing it entirely or fixing it in any way).  But it *is* problematic in a number of ways, saying those problems don't exist, or that they're good things, just isn't something I'm willing to do.

Comment: SO's Q/a format will always be in _some_ way about the OP. the OP is the (only) one that can clarify a unclear question. Otherwise, what incentive would anyone have to ask a question here?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, the OP is the one responsible for ensuring that the question is an acceptable question and that it's answerable.  That doesn't mean that they should be the one responsible for determining what the best answer is though.  I'm not saying that the OP of a question doesn't have *any* responsibilities, I'm just saying that choosing what the best answer is shouldn't' be one of them, because that doesn't serve the site's goals.

Comment: And as I said, one shouldn't see that green check as a marker for the "best" answer. but that's a different issue. Once that's changed, the OP accepting an answer is no longer a "problem".

Comment: @Cerbrus Saying that we shouldn't treat it that way when the site treats it that way, and sends a very strong signal that readers should treat it that way just doesn't mean much.  Most people won't see your (or anyone else's) meta comments saying that they shouldn't treat the answer as the best answer, they're just going to see the answer that the site presents as the best answer.