# Is it ever appropriate to appeal your answer to be chosen over another when it is clearly a better answer (as in, objectively better)?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Some questions I see have accepted answers with other answers that are far more detailed and efficient.

Would it be appropriate to appeal this in that case?

Comment: It's up to the OP to award the checkmark. It is *their choice*, up to and including not awarding it at all. It's fine to educate someone new to SO on how accepting works, but that's about it. Don't fall into the trap of expecting it to be your right to be given the accepted answer mark.

Comment: Certainly not! I just ask because some answers take a lot of time. And in the event they are an objectively better answer...well, you can see where I'm coming from. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you'll be naturally biased towards your answer being better! But again, it's still not your choice which answer is awarded! Instead of answering for the check mark, answer for the future visitor that has the same problem. Aim for long-term usefulness, and you'll be rewarded with upvotes over time.

Comment: That's great advice, good perspective. Thanks man.

Comment: Popularity has never been a decent substitute for correctness.

Comment: Somewhat related: [*Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253752/2751851)

Comment: Popularity? Nah. Just the perks that come with a higher rep.

Comment: @duplode Great post. And I agree. Plus, there could be several great answers that all come together and do a great job of educating on the topic. The accepted answer stamp definitely deters more people to add to the subject matter, even if what they have to say is particularly relevant.

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen On smaller sites, there is often an active effort to respond to quick acceptances by the asker with comments that say 'thanks, and it's your right to accept, but we typically recommend waiting 24 hours before accepting an answer, to encourage more people to contribute great answers' or something along those lines. It doesn't happen on Stack Overflow likely because there are just way too many questions to keep up with.

Comment: @TylerH Good to know! appreciate it.

Comment: I really really dont understand why not even one out of those 12 (at least 12) down voters left a comment with the reason for the down vote. Its really annoying and people dont realize that there is no hope for improvement in such case after all one can only learn from mistakes.

Comment: @rishav *sigh* that's just SO. I've learned I simple have to resign to it or not use the site.

Comment: @Rishav quickly, assuming the downvotes mean what the tooltip of the down arrow says, I'd say it's a lack of research. This is not a new topic for meta, there is a bunch of Q's around acceptance. OP could have found it. Also, when it comes to meta, since DVs don't remove rep, people also use it to express disagreement. As in 'I don't think this is a good idea, you shouldn't do this type of appeal'. Doesn't necessarily mean the question is poor (although the lack of research makes it not high quality...)

Comment: @Patrice Disagreeing is always default. Don't pretend there's any sort of weighing of options. And that's the point - the bigger issue.

Comment: @Patrice Talking generally I'm pretty sure that DVs do remove rep on SO. (Maybe not on meta) There a downvote hits -2 to the OP. (I could be wrong) This question could definitely be a low quality question due to lack of research but is it not the right thing to do to atleast leave behind a little comment saying lack of research , a duplicate question or something similar. One only needs to type in 10 characters, I bet it won't hurt. A new user probably doesn't know much.

Comment: You know that I just have to find a couple of upvoted feature requests or discussions to prove you wrong here? Stop assuming the community is evil and downvotes without logic. Thinking otherwise will not be conducive of anything. You come here on the backfoot and instead of thinking 'hmm maybe I missed something or maybe there is a reason why this isn't this way', you automatically assume you get downvoted for no reason. That won't lead to anything.

Comment: @Rishav I said specifically 'DVs don't remove rep on meta'. Why are you talking about SO here? 2 different subsites, 2 different behaviors (note that you are correct for the main site, DVs will remove rep there). And 'lack of research' is in the tooltip of the down arrow. Do we need to repeat it?

Comment: @Patrice I know man u specifically said about meta. I also wrote *In general* in the beginning. And in talking  about SO here because meta.SO is made for discussion about SO. People do just downvote and move on 80% of the time. And that's the problem. When I was new I got tons of DVs and I had no idea why. I did the complete tour, read the FAQs , visited the help and tip centre. But I was totally blank. Gradually when a few lads left the reason I realised , improvised and improved.

Comment: @Rishav maybe, but if you are coming on a meta question to ask about downvotes,you will get a meta specific answer, as this is important to understand in relation to this question's reception. If you want to talk about commenting on downvotes,there is an Uber dupe cannonical for that somewhere (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s)

Comment: @Rishav It just means that people are answering "no" to this "should I?" question. It is a common way to vote here on Meta but it does have the unfortunate effect of hiding the question as well as sending potentially confusing signals to the OP.

Comment: @TylerH Agreed. If the downvoter bother to share his thoughts why he thinks "no" to will end up in development of the community.

Comment: @Rishav but if it's been discussed time and time again, shouldn't the downvotes be allowed to just say no? Or if I get to the question, see Martin's first comment here and agree with it... Shouldn't I be allowed to just do the question here? Or do we want to force users to repeatedly leave the same comments because some people can't find the original discussions?

Comment: @Pareice Good point. Only if atleast 1 user bothers to leave that tiny comment. And other after downvoteing upvote the comment. It's been the standard way. When someone wants to deliver the same comment they upvote the comment.

Comment: @Rishav but if the justification is in a duplicate that I don't have time to find (let's say I am walking to the office, checking stack on my cell and find this). I shouldn't be allowed to just express 'this isn't researched' with the DV button? Don't get me wrong I see the value in explaining downvotes. I disagree with the stance of 'it **has** to be done or the DV isn't valid' that a lot of new users seem to have.

Comment: @TylerH I respectfully disagree. Downvotes don't simply imply a response of 'no' - they make a statement, being that the quality/worth of the question itself is no worthy. You absolutely know this to be true. So do the downvoters. It's 100% condescension apart from when the question is obviously ridiculous.

Comment: @Patrice Hmm. Agreed. Should not be mandatory but users should atleast consider adding a comment if they can. Infact SO shows this little message when you downvote.

Comment: @TylerH Interesting observation -- I don't think I have ever seen anyone spell that out in any of the downvotes-on-Meta discussions I have seen. On Meta, downvoting for lack of research can be okay (if a full answer to the question is indeed easy to find), and downvoting for disagreement sometimes makes sense (if the question involves a feature request or advances a thesis). However, I'd say that downvoting as a way to answer "no" in other cases is flat out wrong, *even on Meta*.

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen "no" *is* a statement. And no, neither you nor I "absolutely know" why the downvoters downvoted. You *can't* know unless all 11 people come in and own up to their reasoning here.

Comment: @duplode I agree, but that's the problem with a lack of rich tools for measuring community opinion on discussion questions. You either vote, or expend more effort to leave a comment exposing yourself to responses/retribution, or expend a lot more effort to leave an answer exposing yourself to *even more* responses/retribution.

Comment: @TylerH There is also the option of doing nothing and letting someone else write a proper reply. (Also, the risk of retaliation in a scenario involving a genuine question written in a friendly tone by a Meta OP looks small to me.)

Comment: I'm growing tired of this conversation. I do not foresee it going anywhere near any sort of productive outcome and think I'll take it down. To each their own, no disrespect meant here. Good luck to you all.

Comment: @TylerH I'm thinking about posting a Meta question about the issue we exchanged comments about here. If I actually do that, would it be okay for me to quote your comment? (You can be sure I won't attribute the "flat out wrong" view to you.)

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen I would advise that you not take the score of your question so personally. Meta votes do not affect your reputation or your ability to ask questions on the main site *at all*. Even if 11 people think your question lacked research or was low quality... so what? They don't bother to explain why or provide a way to improve, so just ignore that. I mean even the CEO of the company has asked questions and posted answers here that have gotten hundreds of negative votes. You got a good answer and a decent amount of healthy discussion under the question... that is a win in my book.

Comment: @duplode Sure, I don't mind if you quote or screenshot it. I don't claim that that's what these voters here did; I can't know that without them saying so. I'm just saying I have seen that argument used before for prescribing/projecting a reason for downvoting on meta. I would support such a question, though I doubt even if everyone agrees that it will change the voting culture one iota...

Comment: @Aaron it makes sense. You can't remove someone else's time and contribution. You can delete your own though. Saving rep was your decision in relation to your content. Not you removing someone else's content.

Comment: @Patrice Maybe I am unaware, but when deleting SO posts, aren't everyone's comments deleted then as well? What's the difference?

Comment: @TylerH you're right. I need to pump the breaks a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Aaron comments by their very nature are meant to be ephemereal and deleted at a whim. Someone posting a comment should be aware that if it gets removed, it doesn't matter. If someone posts an answer they intend to add to our long lasting repository of knowledge in a permanent way. You shouldn't have the unilateral power over that (especially when 11 members of the community upvoted that answer, indicating they see value in it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is never appropriate to solicit for the accepted answer checkmark. Such comments should be flagged as noise and such content in posts should be edited out. It is the asker's prerogative to pick the answer that helped them the most and/or solved their problem.

When it comes to answers of your own competing with an existing accepted answer, if you have some constructive criticism or important flaw to point out in a competing answer, feel free to do so via comments. But don't say "this is not as good as my answer" even if your answer is better and everyone agrees with you.

Likewise you can also refer to the other answer(s) in your post by pointing out some shortcomings or problems in them (if such things exist). It *is* okay to say in your answer something like "I didn't feel like the accepted answer was efficient/elegant enough, so here is my attempt, which differs by" etc.

If OP comments on a post saying "thanks, this solved my problem" and they simply haven't *picked* an answer as the accepted answer yet, then *do* feel free to nudge them in a comment asking to accept that answer, even if it's yours. Just don't do multiple times, and once they have done so, be sure to go back and delete the comment.

Comment: "ikewise you can also refer to the other answer(s) in your post by pointing out some shortcomings or problems in them (if such things exist). It is okay to say in your answer something like "I didn't feel like the accepted answer was efficient/elegant enough, so here is my attempt, which differs by" etc. "

great point.